# Using font awesome in codepen

Tags: css, stylesheet, codepen

I'm trying to add the styles sheet for font-awesome into a Codepen but seem to be getting nowhere, can anybody help please.

Codepen (https://codepen.io/kellett/pen/YreKaW)

Below is the styles sheet I've inserted in the top of HTML page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's working, you just are using the wrong font-awesome class.

Line 19 should be `<span class="fa fa-search"></span>`.

See this [updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/fontawesome)

---

**Note:** You can also add CDNs in the CodePen settings so you don't have to include it inline in your html.

Answer (score 3):

simply add this http://static.fontawesome.com/css/fontawesome-app.css in css setting panel:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Open settings.
2. On the Pen Settings modal, select the CSS tab
3. In the "Add External Stylesheets/Pens" section, search for `font-awesome`.

[image: pen settings]

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong . **[Check this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PJQzxx)**

`<span class="fa fa-search"></span>` use like this instead of `<span class="fa-search"></span>`.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings on the top right-hand corner. Then paste the CDN code in the box that says "Stuff for <head>." Press Save and Close before adding your Font Awesome tags, which should be formatted like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i>
```

Here's the CodePen. You should see a thumbs up icon on the bottom of the page:
https://codepen.io/calumchilds/pen/boLwVb

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add this link into js setting:
https://use.fontawesome.com/4d74086fc6.js.

[image]